# Read contents of a SQL table into a data grid view

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm using C# .net Windows forms application. I have created a database `resources` in SQL Server 2005 with a table `resourcetable` which has two columns. I need to read the data in the table into a datagridview. I can do this by using the connection string and query by giving the table name.

But my problem is I have a button and if I click on that button, an open dialog box should open and I should be able to select a database among many databases, and in that selected database I have to select one table among many tables.

E.g. select a table of a particular database, and the contents of that table will be displayed in a datagridview.

Comment: So what is your problem? Any specific question or do you want us to do your job in general? Then the answer is "program it".

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn ADO.NET - either Google or Bing for "ADO.NET beginner tutorial", or check out a few of those hits:

- [Using ADO.NET for beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DatabaseAcessWithAdoNet1.aspx)
- [ADO.NET for beginners - part 1](http://devcity.net/Articles/215/1/article.aspx)
- [The C# station ADO.NET tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson01.aspx)

Or if you have a specific problem, change your question to be clearer as to what it is you're having trouble with.